# Linux - Nimbus LookAndFeel : Table Grid Lines are not coming

Tags: java, linux, swing, jtable, nimbus

In my java application I am using NimBusLookAndFeel. I was trying to show grid lines in table.

Following code works perfectly fine on windows but not on Linux (table grid lines do not appear in linux)

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
UIManager.put("Table.showGrid", true);
UIManager.put("Table.intercellSpacing", new Dimension (1,1));
```

Following are java version details on linux

> java version "1.6.0_12" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_12-b04) Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 11.2-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: The Linux java may simply be too old.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Its java version 1.6 update 12 and Nimbus was introduced in JDK 1.6 update 10

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I tried using a newer version of JDK but the problem still persists.                                           root@OMC server]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode)
[root@OMC server]#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to overrive following [Nimbus UIDefaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)

```
try {// UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if (info.getName().equals("Nimbus")) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
            defaults.put("Table.gridColor", new Color (214,217,223));
            defaults.put("Table.disabled", false);
            defaults.put("Table.showGrid", true);
            defaults.put("Table.intercellSpacing", new Dimension(1, 1));
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
```